# Python Gtk3 set or change color for GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf from Gdk.RGBA or Gdk.Color

Tags: python, colors, gtk3

How can I set or change the color of a GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf ?

I can create and fill:

```
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, 32, 16)
pixbuf.fill(0x000000)
```

But how to get a color from from Gdk.RGBA or Gdk.Color?

edit:

I tried so much things now but nothing is working, for example:

```
import webcolors
from gi.repository import Gdk
color = Gdk.color_parse("orange")
hexe = webcolors.rgb_to_hex(color.to_floats())
```

But I still have the problem that I need 0x at the beginning and it have to be a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this was very hard. I finally found an solution:

```
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, True, 8, 16, 16)
color =  Gdk.color_parse("orange")
fillr = (color.red / 256) << 24
fillg = (color.green / 256) << 16
fillb = (color.blue / 256) << 8
fillcolor = fillr | fillg | fillb | 255
pixbuf.fill(fillcolor)
```

Thanks to starcal (https://github.com/ilius/starcal/blob/master/scal3/ui_gtk/desktop.py) for the code and and to http://nullege.com/ helped me to find this.